# Missing settings windows (Ubuntu 17.04 gnome)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to make Caps Lock key switch between input languages.
The answers I find on the web point to Settings->Keyboard->Typing->etc
(example of an answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279141/how-to-allow-for-caps-lock-keyboard-layout-change) However, if I go to Settings->Keyboard I don't see any sub-menus, just the list of all shortcuts. Am I missing anything?

Additionally, I do not have sub-menu 'Keyboard' in System Settings. (where other answers point).

P.S. Just in case, the other ways I tried to make CapsLock switch languages:

1) inside aforementioned shortcut list it's impossible: when I try to set up new shortcut and press CapsLock nothing happens. (I can set up another 'normal' keys for the shortcut, but not CapsLock)

2) inside System Settings there's just no 'Keyboard' sub-menu

3) inside gnome-tweak-tools I set CapsLock as switch between languages (in the Typing section), but it doesn't switch languages.

P.P.S. CapsLock key itself works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/SystemSettings/Keyboard my settings pages are fine. As to why the answer I linked mentions other pages, I believe it's just outdated.

As to how I managed to solve my original task of switching lanuages with CapsLock: method 3 in post scriptum worked after I set shortcut for switching languages to default in Keyboard menu.